# How to Use Vlookup with IF Statement in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Now, let's assume, I have decided on the condition that if the scores scored by an XYZ student are higher than 90, then it will be shown as "Great," otherwise it will be shown as "Good." Now, when I look at the marks, I'm not interested in their real marks, but I just want to see whether they're great or good.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do not pay attention to semicolons between arguments - it's national settings.